# Execute each subtask in parallel in a multithreaded environment

Tags: java, multithreading, guava, executorservice, forkjoinpool

I am working on a library which will take an object **`DataRequest`** as an input parameter and basis on that object, I will construct an URL and then make a call to our app servers using apache http client and then return the response back to the customer who is using our library. Some customer will call the **`executeSync`** method to get the same feature and some customer will call our **`executeAsync`** method to get the data.

- **`executeSync()`** - waits until I have a result, returns the result.
- **`executeAsync()`** - returns a Future immediately which can be processed after other things are done, if needed.

Below is my **`DataClient`** class which has above two methods:

```
public class DataClient implements Client {
  private final ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(16);
  private CloseableHttpClient httpClientBuilder;

  // initializing httpclient only once
  public DataClient() {
    try {
      RequestConfig requestConfig =
          RequestConfig.custom().setConnectionRequestTimeout(500).setConnectTimeout(500)
              .setSocketTimeout(500).setStaleConnectionCheckEnabled(false).build();
      SocketConfig socketConfig =
          SocketConfig.custom().setSoKeepAlive(true).setTcpNoDelay(true).build();

      PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingHttpClientConnectionManager =
          new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
      poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(300);
      poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(200);

      httpClientBuilder =
          HttpClientBuilder.create().setConnectionManager(poolingHttpClientConnectionManager)
              .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).setDefaultSocketConfig(socketConfig).build();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      // log error
    }
  }

  @Override
  public List<DataResponse> executeSync(DataRequest key) {
    List<DataResponse> responsList = null;
    Future<List<DataResponse>> responseFuture = null;

    try {
      responseFuture = executeAsync(key);
      responsList = responseFuture.get(key.getTimeout(), key.getTimeoutUnit());
    } catch (TimeoutException | ExecutionException | InterruptedException ex) {
      responsList =
          Collections.singletonList(new DataResponse(DataErrorEnum.CLIENT_TIMEOUT,
              DataStatusEnum.ERROR));
      responseFuture.cancel(true);
      // logging exception here
    }
    return responsList;
  }

  @Override
  public Future<List<DataResponse>> executeAsync(DataRequest key) {
    DataFetcherTask task = new DataFetcherTask(key, this.httpClientBuilder);
    return this.forkJoinPool.submit(task);
  }
}
```

Below is my **`DataFetcherTask`** class which also has a static class **`DataRequestTask`** which calls our app servers by making URL:

```
public class DataFetcherTask extends RecursiveTask<List<DataResponse>> {
  private final DataRequest key;
  private final CloseableHttpClient httpClientBuilder;

  public DataFetcherTask(DataRequest key, CloseableHttpClient httpClientBuilder) {
    this.key = key;
    this.httpClientBuilder = httpClientBuilder;
  }

  @Override
  protected List<DataResponse> compute() {
    // Create subtasks for the key and invoke them
    List<DataRequestTask> requestTasks = requestTasks(generateKeys());
    invokeAll(requestTasks);

    // All tasks are finished if invokeAll() returns.
    List<DataResponse> responseList = new ArrayList<>(requestTasks.size());
    for (DataRequestTask task : requestTasks) {
      try {
        responseList.add(task.get());
      } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        return Collections.emptyList();
      }
    }
    return responseList;
  }

  private List<DataRequestTask> requestTasks(List<DataRequest> keys) {
    List<DataRequestTask> tasks = new ArrayList<>(keys.size());
    for (DataRequest key : keys) {
      tasks.add(new DataRequestTask(key));
    }
    return tasks;
  }

  // In this method I am making a HTTP call to another service
  // and then I will make List<DataRequest> accordingly.
  private List<DataRequest> generateKeys() {
    List<DataRequest> keys = new ArrayList<>();
    // use key object which is passed in contructor to make HTTP call to another service
    // and then make List of DataRequest object and return keys.
    return keys;
  }

  /** Inner class for the subtasks. */
  private static class DataRequestTask extends RecursiveTask<DataResponse> {
    private final DataRequest request;

    public DataRequestTask(DataRequest request) {
      this.request = request;
    }

    @Override
    protected DataResponse compute() {
      return performDataRequest(this.request);
    }

    private DataResponse performDataRequest(DataRequest key) {
      MappingHolder mappings = DataMapping.getMappings(key.getType());
      List<String> hostnames = mappings.getAllHostnames(key);

      for (String hostname : hostnames) {
        String url = generateUrl(hostname);
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        httpGet.setConfig(generateRequestConfig());
        httpGet.addHeader(key.getHeader());

        try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClientBuilder.execute(httpGet)) {
          HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
          String responseBody =
              TestUtils.isEmpty(entity) ? null : IOUtils.toString(entity.getContent(),
                  StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

          return new DataResponse(responseBody, DataErrorEnum.OK, DataStatusEnum.OK);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
          // log error
        }
      }
      return new DataResponse(DataErrorEnum.SERVERS_DOWN, DataStatusEnum.ERROR);
    }
  }
}
```

For each `DataRequest` object there is a `DataResponse` object. Now once someone calls our library by passing `DataRequest` object, internally we make `List<DataRequest>` object and then we invoke each `DataRequest` object in parallel and return `List<DataResponse>` back where each `DataResponse` object in the list will have response for corresponding `DataRequest` object.

Below is the flow:

- Customer will call `DataClient` class by passing `DataRequest` object. They can call `executeSync()` or `executeAsync()` method depending on their requirements.
- Now in the `DataFetcherTask` class (which is a `RecursiveTask` one of `ForkJoinTask's` subtypes), given a `key` object which is a single `DataRequest`, I will generate `List<DataRequest>` and then invokes each subtask in parallel for each `DataRequest` object in the list. These subtasks are executed in the same `ForkJoinPool` as the parent task.
- Now in the `DataRequestTask` class, I am executing each `DataRequest` object by making an URL and return its `DataResponse` object back.

---

**Problem Statement:**

Since this library is being called in a very high throughput environment so it has to be very fast. For synchronous call, executing in a separate thread is ok here? It will incur extra costs and resources for a Thread along with the cost of context switch of threads in this case so I am little bit confuse. Also I am using `ForkJoinPool` here which will save me in using extra thread pool but is it the right choice here?

Is there any better and efficient way to do the same thing which can be performance efficient as well? I am using Java 7 and have access to Guava library as well so if it can simplify anything then I am open for that as well.

It looks like we are seeing some contention when it runs under very heavy load. Is there any way this code can go into thread contention when runs under very heavy load?

Comment: Sounds like a [ThreadPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) would be useful, but remember that premature optimization is the source of all evil

Comment: @ScaryWombat Agreed and that's why I will do load testing but the question is what I have is reasonable by using ForkJoinPool which is also a specialized form of ThreadPool only. And then the way I am using executeSync method is right or not?

Comment: What kind of contention you are seeing? Maybe for heavy load `new ForkJoinPool(16);` is not enough, try to increase the `16` to a greater value

Answer (score 0):

I think in your situation it's better to use async http call, see link: [HttpAsyncClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/quickstart.html). And you don't need to use thread pool.

In executeAsync method create empty CompletableFuture<DataResponse>() and pass it to client call, there in callback call set the result of completableFuture by calling complete on it (or completeExceptionally if exceptions raise).
ExecuteSync method implementation looks good.

**edit:**

For java 7 it's only need to replace a completableFuture to promise implementation in guava, like ListenableFuture or anything similar

Answer (score 0):

The choice to use the `ForkJoinPool` is correct, its designed for efficiency with many small tasks:

> A ForkJoinPool differs from other kinds of ExecutorService mainly by virtue of employing work-stealing: all threads in the pool attempt to find and execute tasks submitted to the pool and/or created by other active tasks (eventually blocking waiting for work if none exist). This enables efficient processing when most tasks spawn other subtasks (as do most ForkJoinTasks), as well as when many small tasks are submitted to the pool from external clients. Especially when setting asyncMode to true in constructors, ForkJoinPools may also be appropriate for use with event-style tasks that are never joined.

I suggest to try the `asyncMode = true` in the constructor since in your case the tasks are never joined:

```
public class DataClient implements Client {
    private final ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(16, ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory, null, true);
...
}
```

For the `executeSync()` you can use the `forkJoinPool.invoke(task)`, this is the managed way to do a synchronous task execution in the pool for resources optimisation:

```
@Override
public List<DataResponse> executeSync(DataRequest key) {
  DataFetcherTask task = new DataFetcherTask(key, this.httpClientBuilder);
  return this.forkJoinPool.invoke(task);
}
```

If you can use Java 8 then there is a common pool already optimised: `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()`

Comment: Can  you provide me an example where I am supposed to use `asyncMode=true`? And also how does my `executeSync()` method will look like? Just little bit confuse about this.

Comment: I added some example in the answer

Comment: So that means I don't need to call `executeAsync` method inside `executeSync` and just do what you suggested? If yes, then how does timeout come into the picture now? I mean for sync if calls timesout then I was returning timeout response back. How will that work here?

Comment: The `forkJoinPool.invoke(task)` doesn't handle the timeout, simply it executes the `task.compute()` method and awaits the result, the only timeout in this case is the HttpClient one. To manage a timeout your method `executeSync()` is fine.

Comment: @david, you manage the timeout in the `executeSync`, but what about the timeout in the `executeAsync`? Every caller must manage it?

Comment: Yes for async one, the caller is going to manage that. requirement I had was for sync one I need to return proper DataResponse back which tells what happened exactly and also anyone can call async as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137679/discussion-between-david-and-teg).